# r - How to find name of Max vlaue in Closeness Centrality igraph output

Tags: r, max, igraph

I use of **igraph package in R** for work on graph. I get **Closeness Centrality** with igraph method, and I want to find maximum value in Closeness with name.

```
library(igraph)
# Create of Graph Matrix for Test Closeness Centrality
g <- read.table(text="A B 
     1 2
     2 3
     3 4
     4 5", header=TRUE)
gadj <- get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(g), directed=FALSE))
igObject <- graph.adjacency(gadj) # convert adjacency matrix to igraph object
gCloseness <- closeness(igObject) # Assign Closeness to Variable for print
```

When I use of `max()` I get maximum value of Closeness and when use of `names()` back NULL.

```
> max(gCloseness)
  [1] 0.1666667
```

other:

```
> names(max(gCloseness))
  NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `V(igObject)[which.max(gCloseness)]`

Comment: Show only value, my result is : "Vertex sequence: [1] 4"

Comment: The output for `V(igObject)[which.max(gCloseness)]` with your example data is `3`. If you label the nodes, i'd be the label, e.g. for `V(igObject)$name <- letters[1:5]; V(igObject)[which.max(gCloseness)]` the output is `c`

Comment: Yep! thanks. my training data have not label. I test on another data set is right.